# Dart: Root folder of relative paths differs in Dartium and Chrome

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

Just upgraded to Dart 1.3.3 and observed different root folders of relative resource paths in Dartium vs. Chrome (compiled via dart2js).

My folder structure is as follows:

```
web/
  elements/
    my_element.css
    my_element.dart
    my_element.html
```

Until now, I've referenced `my_element.css` via

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="my_element.css">
```

in `my_element.html`.

But since upgrading to 1.3.3 I get a "404 Not found" error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
  [...]/web/my_element.css
```

It seems, that the `elements`-folder is now ignored on specifying the relative path to the css-file.

Changing the path to:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="elements/my_element.css">
```

solves the problem in Dartium, but in Chrome (when compiled via dart2js), again a 404-error occurs:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
  [...]/web/elements/elements/my_element.css
```

In contrast to Dartium, it seems, that the elements-folder isn't ignored in Chrome.

But how to solve this dilemma?

Comment: I think you should file a bug.

Comment: "my-element" - sounds like polymer? In case you use it, which version are you using? Which other packages are you using?

Comment: where did you place the `rel="stylesheet"`?

Comment: @Robert, correct, I'm using polymer, version 0.9.5+2. Other packages are: animation, crypto, intl, quiver. `rel="stylesheet"` is placed before the href-attribute. The whole link element is the first statement in template: `<polymer-element name="my-element"><template>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="my_element.css">[...]</template></polymer-element>`

Comment: OK, could you also try to move your .css file to the lib directory of you package and then use href="packages/<your_package>/my-element.css" and see if that works?

Comment: @Robert: No, that doesn't work: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
  [...]/web/packages/<name of my package>/my_element.css`

Comment: FYI: I've filed a bug: https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=18563&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Area%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary%20Modified

Answer (score 1):

This issue was [marked as Fixed](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=18563#c17) in July. It appears to have been a bug in the transformer that inlined imports; which is why it only affected Chrome (Dartium runs the code natively, and does not use the transformer).